# android autocomplete textview and search contact list

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am new to android. I have a keypad and a contact list . I would like to search in contact list using the keypad and the `autocompleteTextView`. Can someone give me some examples ? I didn't find on the internet examples with this type of problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      ========>phoneArr====> which contains ur all contacts
    if(phoneArr.length > 0 )
    {
      AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.empphonenumber);
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.auto_list_item, phoneArr);
      textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

`=======>`auto_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:textColor="#000">
```

In this way you can add adapter to the `Autocomplete listview`.Its better than previous one

Comment: what do you recomand? should I add all the contact list persons in a database? will it take a long time to display all the database elements? hwo should i do this? what if i have over 2000 contact persons?

Comment: i just showed example. you can implement in your own way. there is no need of adding contacts to the database. i will tell you how to use autocomplete list. just wait

Comment: i changed my answer.check once

Comment: can you pleaaw tell me what is phoneArr? how to define and declare it? please??

Comment: also what is R.layout.auto_list_item? can you please tell me?

Comment: just create a auto_list_item xml file . i will add that one also.just wait

Comment: get all contacts in a array named phoneArr

Comment: what if i have over 2000 contact list persons? Should I still use an array? Also should rhe array contan the names and the phone numbers or just the names? I need osmethign very efficient. Thank you for your response

Comment: i also what to ttell you that the completettextview has to display the contact person what matches with the keys i press from the keypad

Comment: @Ramkiran : Whre is phoneArr ?

Comment: that is the array where you are all contacts reside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create adpater to set in your auto complete textView.

Refer Following Links:

[linkone](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/auto-complete-text-view-android.html)

[linktwo](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/example-of-autocompletetextview.html)